# Configure StructureMap to choose subclass implementation over baseclass implementation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I have two implementations of an interface `IJsonConverter<T>`. One implemantation is for a base class called `Vehicle` , that is for `IJsonConverter<Vehicle>` and the other implementation is for a subclass to `Vehicle` called `Car`, that is an implementation for `IJsonConverter<Car>`. When i try to inject an implementation for `IJsonConverter<Car>` I get an exception, my guess is that StructureMap does not know which implementation to choose.

Is it possible to configure StructureMap to choose the subclass implementation somehow?

I have configured StructureMap like this:

```
...
assemblyScanner.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IJsonConverter<>));
...
```

This is the classes I'm using:

Baseclass

```
public class Vehicle {}
```

Subclass

```
public class Car : Vehicle {}
```

Baseclass converter

```
public class VehicleJsonConverter : IJsonConverter<Vehicle> {}
```

Subclass converter

```
public class CarJsonConverter : IJsonConverter<Car> {}
```

Error message:

> StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: No default Instance
>   is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type
>   'IJsonConverter'
>
> No default instance is specified.  The current configuration for type
>   IJsonConverter is:

```
PluginType          ...  Description
IJsonConverter<Car>      WebApplication.Json.Converters.VehicleJsonConverter
                         WebApplication.Json.Converters.CarJsonConverter
```